# How to grep the output of a command inside a shell script when scheduling using cron

Tags: shell, cron, grep, amazon-emr

I have a simple shell script where I need to check if my EMR job is running or not and I am just printing a log but it does not seem to work properly when scheduling the script using cron as it always prints the if block statement because the value of "status_live" var is always empty so if anyone can suggest what is wrong here otherwise on manually running the script it works properly.

```
#!/bin/sh

status_live=$(yarn application -list | grep -i "Streaming App")

if [ -z $status_live ] 
then
  echo "Running spark streaming job again at: "$(date) &
else
  echo "Spark Streaming job is running, at: "$(date)
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script cannot run in `cron` because cron script has no environment context at all.

For example try to run your script as another use `nobody` that has no shell.

```
 sudo -u nobody <script-full-path>
```

It will fail because it has no environment context.

The solution is to add your user environment context to your script. Just add `source` to your `.bash_profile`

```
 sed -i "2a source $HOME/.bash_profile" <script-full-path>
```

Your script should look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
source /home/<your user name>/.bash_profile

status_live=$(yarn application -list | grep -i "Streaming App")

if [ -z $status_live ] 
then
  echo "Running spark streaming job again at: "$(date) &
else
  echo "Spark Streaming job is running, at: "$(date)
fi
```

Now try to run it again with user `nobody`, if it works than `cron` will work as well.

```
 sudo -u nobody <script-full-path>
```

Note that `cron` has no standard output. and you will need to redirect standard output from your script to a log file.

```
<script-full-path> >> <logfile-full-path>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# $? will have the last command status in bash shell scripting
# your complete command here below and status_live is 0  if it finds in grep (i.e. true in shell if condition.)
yarn application -list | grep -i "Streaming App"
status_live=$?
echo status_live: ${status_live}
if [ "$status_live" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "success
else
    echo "fail" 
fi
```

Comment: Actually the problem is that the above shell script was also running fine when I was manually running the script, but on scheduling it using a cron it does not work as expected and same is happening with this script as well.

Comment: [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: @YashTandon looks like in cron, it might be running under different shell environment.

Comment: @YashTandon  SHELL=/bin/bash in the cron file before your command running, just to make sure its running under bash

Comment: @tripleee $? will give always sucess or failure of previous command in shell

Comment: It does, but you obviously need to read the linked question about why to generally avoid it.

Comment: Probably `yarn` gives different output (because you haven't activated its environment, perhaps?) and then the syntax changes here will not change the result.