# cron.hourly script is only run manually

Tags: cron, sh

It does not seem that file I put to `/etc/cron.hourly` does not seem to work

It's called `cron_hourly_homepage`, so it does not seem that its filename issue. Ownership seems alright as well: `-rwxr-xr-x`

`run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly` sees this file, `run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly` can run it as well

Would like to get it fixed, so no crontab recommendations are necessary :D

```
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-12-27 20:20:40 GMT; 1 day 23h ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 401 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
        CPU: 9.213s
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─401 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Dec 29 17:19:01 raspberrypi CRON[9255]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Dec 29 17:19:01 raspberrypi CRON[9255]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 29 18:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[9427]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Dec 29 18:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[9428]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: Is cron enabled as a service?

Comment: @HSchmale Yeap, it seems to be active, added to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to forget cron scripts are running without a shell and no environment context.
Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523039/6266192)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be part of the issue and I switched to a bit different approach. Will get back to it sometime in the future